# C++ boost signal copy connections

Tags: c++, boost-signals

I know boost::signal isn't copyable, but is there anyway one could iterate over the connections and copy the connections? As in, take all the slots and them to another signal?

I ask because I have a class that's acting as a wrapper around an array, and the class signals whenever data in the array changes. I was using pointers to a signal, but obviously it doesn't make sense to copy the signal pointer with the rest of the object.

So I'm wondering if it's possible to iterate the signal and copy the functions that are attached?

If I can't do this with boost signal, is there a signal library that will let me do this?

Comment: "I ask because..." Thank you for including this information. +1

Comment: This seems to be what you are looking for:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816161/is-there-a-way-to-connect-a-boost-signal-directly-to-another-signal?rq=1

HTH